# Replacing bathroom exhaust fan

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

[image: center switch is for fan]
[image: new fan wiring]
[image]
Old fixture:  combination fan and light
New fixture: fan only

New fixture wiring: 1 white, 1 black, 1 green
Existing wiring: 1 white, 1 black, 1 bare copper, 1 red

Wall switch: red & black twisted together, black

To hook up wiring do I: white to white, black & red to black, and green to bare copper?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the picture, but it basically shows us nothing except for the end of a generic wire. Would you add photos of the insides of the boxes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't overcomplicate it. Sounds like you had a "fan and light" with wiring to be able to be switched separately, but actually wired so they were always switched together.

So, remove and insulate the red (what you call pink, but it's both commonly and clearly in your pictures: red) wire at both ends. Twisting on a small wirenut and taping that is a typical approach. You don't need it unless you want to have separately switched fan and light on a fixture that supports that, perhaps the next remodel.

Black to black, white to white, bare to green, call it a day.

Yes, you COULD leave the red and black together, but it's not actually right to do that if they are going to the same wire - fine when you had two separate wires at the fan, not fine without that.

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation of the red wire. You are correct that the switch with the red & black wired together it was so that the light & fan would come on/go off together. I can now finish my install correctly following your explanation.